# Evaluating a complex integral over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute $\displaystyle \int_{\left|z \right|=1} \frac{z^7}{z^2+4}dz$

Observe that $z^7$ is a product of analytic functions, so it's analytic. Furthermore, $z^2+4$ is analytic for the same reason, so the function $\frac{z^7}{z^2+4}$ is a quotient of analytic functions, implying that it's analytic everywhere except the points $\pm 2i$. Let $\Omega$ be an open disk $D_R(0)$ with radius $1<R<2$. Then $f(z)$ is analytic in $D_R(0)$ because $\left|2i-0\right|^2=4>R^2$. Since the Jordan curve $\left|z \right|=1$ is contained in $D_R(0)$, we may apply Cauchy's integral theorem, which implies that the integral evaluates to $0$.

Is this work correct? The Cauchy Integral Theorem (there are a couple different versions in the text) states that if $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain $\Omega$ and if $\Gamma$ is a Jordan curve inside $\Omega$ with interior contained in $\Omega$, then $\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz=0$.

Comment: Did you mean $\displaystyle \oint_{\left|z \right|=1} \frac{z^7}{z^2+4}dz$?

Comment: @KennyLau My book doesn't write the integrals like that for some reason... but I've seen them like that in other sources. Are they interchangeable in this setting?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is sound.  The integrand is analytic in and on the unit disk and therefore CIT guarantees the integral is zero.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks for the feedback!

Comment: and you"ll need the [Cauchy integral theorem with holomorphic instead of analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) (for proving then the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), and hence that every holomorphic function on $\Omega$ is analytic on $\Omega$)